# New column with list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

Please use the following code to get idea of data

````
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
import re
from collections import defaultdict,Counter
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import os
tqdm.pandas()
from ast import literal_eval
# nltk imports, note that these outputs may be different if you are using colab or local jupyter notebooks
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize```

from urllib import request
import pandas as pd
module_url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luisespinosaanke/cmt309-portfolio/master/data_portfolio_21.csv"
module_name = module_url.split('/')[-1]
print(f'Fetching {module_url}')
#with open("file_1.txt") as f1, open("file_2.txt") as f2
with request.urlopen(module_url) as f, open(module_name,'w') as outf:
  a = f.read()
  outf.write(a.decode('utf-8'))

df = pd.read_csv('data_portfolio_21.csv')
# this fills empty cells with empty strings
df = df.fillna('')
````

I have a dataframe with a column of strings:

```
df.subr_faved_by
```

Output looks like:

```
1        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...   
2        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...         
3        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...
```

and I need to create new column called 'subr_faved_by_as_list' which contains list of strings

That's my current code

```
def transform_faves(df):
  df['subr_faved_by_as_list'] = df.subr_faved_by.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(', '))
  return df
```

```
df = transform_faves(df)
```

```
df.subr_faved_by_as_list
```

My output looks exactly the same. How can I know if new column has list of strings or is it still string?

That's output:

```
0        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...    
1        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...   
2        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...   
3        ['vergil_never_cry', 'Jelegend', 'pianoyeah', ...
```

Comment: can you provide an unambiguous input/output as dataframe constructor?

Comment: You can check each datatype of the column by using .dtypes

Comment: It seems that new column is not list. It is just a string